# Getting different results at different times when running in threads

Tags: java, json, multithreading

```
@Path("/getVersion")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List getVersion(String getVersionJson) throws InterruptedException {
        List outputList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(getVersionJson);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArr.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(j);
                String ip = jsonObj.getString("ipaddress");
                String username = jsonObj.getString("username");
                String password = jsonObj.getString("password");

                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        //outputList.add(ip);
                        final String connectionStatus = getSSHConnection(ip, username, password);
                        // outputList.add(connectionStatus);
                        if (connectionStatus.equals("Connected")) {
                            // outputList.add(connectionStatus);
                            //Version Check
                            expect.send("bwshowver" + "\n");
                            if (expect.expect("$") > -1) {
                                String contt = "";
                                contt = (expect.before);
                                if (contt != null && contt != "") {

                                    contt = contt.replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
                                    contt = contt.replaceAll(" +", " ");

                                    String splitter[] = contt.split("\n");

                                    for (int i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
                                        if (splitter[i].contains("Patches")) {
                                            final String patches = splitter[i];
                                        }
                                        //version
                                        if (splitter[i].contains("version")) {
                                            // final String version = splitter[i];
                                            outputList.add(splitter[i]);

                                        }

                                    }

                                } else {
                                    final String v1 = "Error in version check";
                                    System.out.println("Error in version check");
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            outputList.add(connectionStatus);
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            final String v = "Error";
            //     logger.error("Exception in getVersion Function-ServService Class: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            stopSSH();
        }
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        //outputList.add("ffk");
        // outputList.add("f");
        return outputList;
    }
```

I have created a method using Threads.  In this method I am sending a jsonarray which consists of json objects.  Previously I created this method without threads and it was working properly.  Now after changing it into threads, I am getting different results at different times.  Can you suggest to me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Instead of the Thread.sleep, use a CountDownLatch to wait for all the results to come in

Comment: Also, make your output list thread-safe (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)

Comment: He does have multiple threads filling in the array in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 major things you can improve in the code above:

- Use thread safe collections when modifying them from multiple threads. If the collection doesn't explicitly mention that it's thread-safe, you will need to either grab locks yourself or switch to a thread-safe collection
- Using a Thread.sleep() for synchronization is generally a bad idea. You should use more precise methods of synchronization to avoid flaky behavior. I've chosen to use a CountDownLatch here, you could use other synchronization tools.
- Exceptions thrown inside threads don't propagate up to the main thread but may just bubble up inside that thread and never be noticed. You want to be able to notice exceptions thrown inside the runnable and handle it at the end. I will also modify the code to show you a rough guide how to handle exceptions.

Going to answer your question in bare-bones format and you can hopefully make the adjustments to your code:

```
public List getVersion(String getVersionJson)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    // You must use a thread-safe list.
    final List outputList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
    // This reference is used to keep track of exceptions thrown
    // in the runnable.
    final AtomicReference<Exception> exceptionReference =
        new AtomicReference(null);
    // This latch acts as a synchronization barrier so that all threads
    // must have put data into outputList before the code will go
    // past the latch.await() call
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(jsonArr.length());
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArr.length(); j++) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {   
                     // Do network I/O stuff
                     outputList.add(resultFromNetworkStuff);
                     latch.countDown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     // Set the exception for later retrieval
                     exceptionReference.compareAndSet(null, e);
                }
            }                        
        }.start();
    }

    // Wait for all the threads to finish before continuing.
    try {
        latch.await();
    } finally {
        // Even if we're interrupted, we want to close the connection.
        closeSSH();
    }
    if (exceptionRef.get() != null) {
        // Throw any exceptions we see in our threads.
        throw exceptionRef.get();
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to explain _what_ is wrong and _how_ to fix it instead of just dumping a new code block.

Comment: I was trying to do that in-line as code comments, and most of the "what" was mentioned in the comments under the question but I will add additional info to the answer as well as going into more detail about the error handling

Answer (score 1):

You put your main thread to sleep for some hard coded period of time. And during that time multiple other threads push data in parallel into a shared list. This cannot work by definition.

When your other thread is done within the 20 seconds, all fine. But if not, your method does return whatever the other threads collected so far. And worse, that other threads keeps updating that list which you already returned.

You have to make sure that the inner threads

- are not accessing that result list in that uncontrolled manner (overwriting each other!)
- are all done before returning from this method.

Don't apply some concept in your code because you heard of it without understanding what you are doing. You have not much clue how to work with java threads and what it means using them. Thus study this stuff instead of blindly pushing it into your code. Learn how to use threads using simple examples; instead of pulling them into your production code like this.

Then: your catch block is throwing away error information! That is always a bad idea. Same for your approach of pushing error information as strings in your result list.

Beyond that: read Clean Code by Robert Martin. Your code would benefit much more from that than from you adding threads for no reason.

Comment: It was me who downvoted it, I thought you were being too harsh criticizing his skills based on what little evidence you have. Also, he does have "MULTIPLE" threads, so he will get the benefit of his I/O not being done serially but in parallel. There is much room for improvement in the code in general but we shouldn't be too judgmental and try reach at the heart of the problems he encountered by switching to threads. And what better way to learn than by trying something out?

Comment: Appreciated, I reworked parts of the answer. I actually missed the loop part. But I still think that he is doing things in the wrong order. You don't learn to juggle while you are learning to ride the unicycle. Meaning: you start by working a good tutorial, and when you understand what you are doing you pull it into your production code. Right now he is doing 3 to 5 complicated things at once. That is a very inefficient approach. And thanks for giving that explanation. Will upvote your answer just for that :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help.I am completly new to this.So I am trying out all possible ways to get to the solution.@muzzlator @GhostCat